# Looping through Array and add into collection with Meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, meteor

I have a dynamic form where you can add input fields:

```
Template.decisionSetUp.events({
 'click #addInput':function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.categoryContainer').append('<input type="text" name="categoryName"  class="form-control categoryTitle" placeholder="Kategorien">')
 }
});
```

Now i want to get the values of the input fields and push them into an array inside of a collection. 
The problem is that i dont know how to fill the array correctly?! What am i missing???

```
Template.decisionSetUp.events({
    'click #start':function(event,t){
      event.preventDefault();
      $('.categoryTitle').each(function() { 
        var title = $(this).val();
        categoryTitle[] = title;
      }); 
Questions.insert({
    category: categoryTitle,
});
```

After this i send it to the DOM.

```
Template.decision.helpers({
    category: function(){
      return this.category;
    }
  })
```

HTML

```
  <template name="decision">
        {{#each category}}
            {{this}}
        {{/each}}  
  </template>
```

Would be great if you could help me!

Comment: What is happening now which isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not adding your values to the `categoryTitles` array.

This should fix your problem:

```
Template.decisionSetUp.events({
    'click #start': function(event, t) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var categoryTitles = [];
        $('.categoryTitle').each(function(index) {
            var title = $(this).val();
            categoryTitles[index] = title;
        });
        Questions.insert({
            category: categoryTitles
        });
    }
});
```

Here is a [MeteorPad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/3WvGzTYLJGbCjpysM/Looping-through-array).

---

Furthermore, I noticed that your `#addInput` event handler is missing the `event` parameter.

Comment: Thank you very much! Saved my day :)